# Logging Hibernate SELECT statements into their own log files

Tags: hibernate, grails, log4j

We will have a full UAT for the next two weeks before our Grails 2.4.4 application goes live. I want to log all `SELECT` statements generated by Hibernate4 that will be executed by then so I could develop properly optimized database indexes. Is there a configuration in Grails or Tomcat that will log `SELECT` statements into a `.log` file distributed per day similar to `catalina.YYYY-MM-dd.log`? I have configured `log4j` to log the queries through `Config.groovy`:

```
log4j.main = {
    ...
    debug 'org.hibernate.SQL', 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg'
    ...
}
```

It logs it on `catalina.out`. Can I configure it so that it will append it to a different log file, let's say `hibernate.YYYY-MM-dd.log`? I do not mind if the parameter will be replaced by `?`, it is fine as long as I can get the `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot configure it to create separate files for `hibernate.SQL` logs through @Daniel's answer. But since my team needs to record the queries starting tomorrow, I decided just manually extract the required logs from `catalina.out` instead.

First, enable logging of `SQL` statements of your Grails Application before creating a war

```
log4j.main = {
    ...
    debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
    ...
}
```

The application will log all `SQL` statements into `catalina.out`, which by the way, will cause the file to become unnecessarily large. Now we need to schedule a cron task every start of the day to extract the statements from the previous day and compile them into a separate daily file.

```
cat catalina.out | grep "$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%Y-%m-%d').*DEBUG hibernate.SQL" | cut -d " " -f 8- | sort | uniq | sed 's/$/;\n/' > "hibernate.$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%Y-%m-%d').log"
```

The beakdown of the bash script is as follow:

1. `cat catalina.out` Fetch the source file.
2. `grep "$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%Y-%m-%d').*DEBUG hibernate.SQL"` Filter only lines that start with the date yesterday (that you get through this part: `$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%Y-%m-%d')`) and that has the string `DEBUG hibernate.SQL` somewhere in between the string.
3. `cut -d " " -f 8-` Remove the first part of the line `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,xxx [http-bio-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-xx-exec-x] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  -`. Our line should immediately start with `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`.
4. `sort` Sorts the line, alphabetically *(optional)*.
5. `uniq` Remove duplicate lines *(optional)*.
6. `sed 's/$/;\n/'` append a semicolon and a new line at the end of each line.
7. `> "hibernate.$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%Y-%m-%d').log"` Save the output to a new file `hibernate.YYYY-MM-dd.log`.

I prefer to not use this "hacky" solution if not for the urgency, we need a solution by tomorrow after all. If someone can still provide the proper way to configure this through `log4j`, Grails `Config.groovy`, or Tomcat, will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have a grails 2 application to test this on, but I believe you can configured named appenders like so :

```
log4j = { root ->
  appenders {
    rollingFile name: "sqlLog", file: "target/sql.log" as String
  }
}
```

and then point particular logging to a named appender like so:

```
 debug sqlLog: 'org.hibernate.SQL', 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg'
```